# Reactive object from a lib and slow reactivity

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am working on a small chess website based on fastAPI and Vue 3 (composition API).
The chess logic is managed by the chessjs lib from which I can instanciate a chess object with a full package of handy methods.
In order to synchronize my component and my chess object, I created a chess reactive:

```
let chess = reactive(new Chess())
```

A lot of computed properties and template linked to those properties later, I just figured out that all methods calculation launched on the proxy become very slow compared to the raw object (example, looking for the possible moves from a position takes 3ms with the raw object and 180ms with the proxy). This is independant from the quantity of rendering demanded.
I understand that Vue needs to check what needs a render or an update but I find it pretty awkward.

What am I missing here?

My workaround for now is to use the raw object and use a computed prop which depends on refs hat are updated by some functions that are trigged with event:

```
click on UI (or whatever other event) => triggers a function that use the raw chess method that returns some array and update a ref => updates a computed prop based on the ref => makes the template update
```

instead of

```
click on UI (or whatever other event) => call chess.method() that updates the chess proxy object => makes the template update
```

I feel like I am not use Vue as it should be...

Can someone give me some advices?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be making the entire `Chess` instance reactive since it likely contains a significant amount of internal properties, most of which are not necessary to detect a change. Since `chess.js` doesn't look it has any "listener" methods for detecting a change to the board, the correct solution would be to use a `shallowRef` (https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-advanced.html#shallowref) and manually call `triggerRef` (https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-advanced.html#triggerref) whenever you make changes to the chess board.

Comment: Nice, I will look into your solution. Thanks